# Lock on object in multi threading

Tags: java

I have a question here in **object locking** in java.
Ex. code:

```
public class A 
{
    private static A a = null; // singleton instance

    private A()
    {

    }

    public static synchronized A getInst()
    {
        if (a == null)
        {
            a = new A();
        }
        return a;
    }

    public synchronized void method1()
    {
        //some action
    }

    public synchronized void method2()
    {
        //some action
    }
}
```

When a thread (say *thread-1*) is working inside `method1()` then *thread-1* acquires **lock** on the singleton object. But another thread (say *thread-2*) wants to enter in to the `method2()` then it will enter **without waiting** *thread-1* to release the lock. How this lock is shared by both *thread-1* and *thread-2*?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But another thread (say thread-2) wants to enter in to the method2 then it will enter without waiting thread-1 to release the lock.

It won't.

At one time only one thread can acquire the lock on an object.

So, unless `thread-1` releases the lock, `thread-2` can't execute `method2`.

Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/thread_basics.html).

Comment: but i observed that both method1 and method2 executed in parallel.

Comment: @G.S how did you test your code and how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I broke my head on this :( Finally found problem in my original code. You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `synchronized` blocks using a specific lock object instead of synchronizes methods.
In such a case it is also easy to block just specific parts of methods where the lock is needed which might speed up multithreaded access if you don't need to synchronize the whole method.

e.g.

```
Object lock = new Object;
public void method1() {
    synchronized(lock) {
      // do stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a singleton class only one instance will be available. so when calling synchronized methods it will lock that single instance. If more than one synchronized methods present,only one method will be executed at a time. Other need to wait for previous method to release the lock. So basically only one thread exists for this singleton class.

If you want other methods not to be affected because of other methods lock, use synchronized block with object lock in singleton class.

```
private final Object object1 = new Object();
private final Object object2 = new Object();

public void method1 {
    synchronized(object1) {
    ....
    }
}

public void method2 {
    synchronized(object2) {
    ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both **synchronized** methods are *instance* methods so, multiple threads will not be able to access them at same time if all of them refer to *same instance*. In you case this is true, because you only have one instance of your class (**singleton** pattern), and as a result if one thread is accessing `method1()` then other thread accessing `method2()` will go in wait state, until thread1 releases the lock or `method1()` is executed completely.

Answer (score 0):

> But another thread (say thread-2) wants to enter in to the method2
>   then it will enter without waiting thread-1 to release the lock.

While thread1 executes `method1()` which is synchronized using the *instance* of A, thread2 will wait before it can execute `method2()` which is also synchronized using the same *instance* of A (since it is **Singleton**)

You can consider it as synchronized **code blocks** (*Critical Section*) instead of synchronized methods such as :

```
public void method1()
{
    synchronized (this)
    {
        //some action
    }
}

public void method2()
{
    synchronized (this)
    {
        //some action
    }
}
```

Considering such, you can see `this` refers to the **same** instance (object lock) for both methods